# Filter a table to remove duplicates from one column only, bottom to top

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data that looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | ba |
| b | c | ba |
| d | w | vo |
| g | z | ba |

There are duplicate values in column B and C, but I only want to remove duplicates from col B. The result should look like this, keeping the last row that contains a duplicate in column B:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | c | ba |
| d | w | vo |
| g | z | ba |

I need to use =filter and not the Remove Duplicates tool. So far, my formulas only either return col B or display an error. I've tried:

`=unique(B2:B5)`

`=filter(A2:C5,unique(B2:B5)=B2:B5)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `XMATCH` with a fourth parameter of `-1`:

```
=LET(
    ζ, A2:C5,
    ξ, INDEX(ζ, , 2),
    FILTER(ζ, XMATCH(ξ, ξ, , -1) = SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ)))
)
```

Comment: i knew there is a better way. Very concise.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(A1:C4,SORT(XMATCH(UNIQUE(B1:B4),B1:B4,,-1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably there are simpler ways of achieving it:

```
=LET(in, A1:C4, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)), B,INDEX(in,,2),
 cnt, MAP(B,seq,LAMBDA(x,s, ROWS(FILTER(B, (seq <= s) * (B=x))))),
 idx,UNIQUE(MAP(B,LAMBDA(x, FILTER(seq, (B=x) * (cnt=MAX(FILTER(cnt, B=x))))))),
 CHOOSEROWS(in,SORT(idx)))
```

**Note**: Adding `SORT` ensures the expected ordering in the output. Credit to @JvdV from his solution.

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The name `cnt`, counts total current and previous repeated values for each value of `B` via `MAP`. The name `idx`, finds the index position where the max counts happens for a given `B` value. Finally, we select the rows via `CHOOSEROWS` for the index positions identified.